# I need to authenticate users with Facebook through C#, without the JS SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, oauth

I realize this sort of question has been asked many times before, but I'm looking for a quickly usable code base to implement ONLY the following: SSO login through Facebook as an external authentication, and retrieval of the current user's email (given that they grant access). I am limited to a c# environment and it seems like the c# solutions or implementations are few and far between. JS isn't acceptable in this situation, and I seem to continually hit the wall of "use the Facebook JS SDK with Graph API".

Has ANYBODY created a primarily server-side solution to the simple act of authentication and subsequent user data retrieval in c#? All I ultimately need is the email address.

My biggest issue is again, this must be a mostly server-side implementation and the resources most widely documented are all PHP and/or JavaScript oriented.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance...I'm about out of options...

Context: This would be a SSO sort of situation for many users coming to one site and not having to create a login...the catch is that after the authentication takes place, I must get their email (provided they agree).

I've gone through outdated libraries, solutions have much more to do with wall and page interaction and the like. My needs are incredibly straightforward. Need authentication and email retrieval.

I have an app already registered with FB, and I have gotten as far as getting a valid access token of type "bearer". Here's where I get lost...

Again, I cannot use the FB JS based SDK. Ugh

EDIT: I tried using the library from [Piotr Gankiewicz](https://piotrgankiewicz.com/2017/02/06/accessing-facebook-api-using-c#), but it seems built for a much more involved purpose. I just can't seem to figure on what should be a relatively easy process.

EDIT 2: I began this process using the "Facebook Login" product, but it seems to break down at the point after authenticationg, and at which I request "email" in scope. No errors, just no email, and this with test and real accounts I control.

Everything I find starts referring to the SDK and using the Graph API. I really don't know what I'm missing.

EDIT 3: Quick example of what I've done (and no, this isn't all of it, but it is the most meaningful beginning):

Link to:
https://www.facebook.com/v3.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=[Client_Id]&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44304/auth/facebook&response_type=code&scope=public_profile,email&state=[Long_Code_To_Verify_Call]

I use the results of that post to complete and GET the following:
string getTokenUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/oauth/access_token?client_id=[Client_Id]&scope=email&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44304/auth/facebook&client_secret=[Client_Secret]&code=" + [Code_Returned_From_Previous_Post];

After the simplicity of the initial login request,k the Graph API seems like overkill for my purposes. This is also the first time I've attempted to implement an OAuth solution...

Comment: You just need to play web requests with the users token to the Graph API. Use the HttpClient in System.Net.Http.

Comment: @BlueWater86 I have actually attempted several calls with the returned access_token of type "bearer", using HttpClient, but I haven't been able to find anything in the way of an example that DOESN'T use the FB JavaScript based SDK. I'm trying to find a simple syntax layout (most likely derived from the SDK) that I can emulate with server-side calls instead of client... C#

Comment: I feel like I'm right on the edge of it, but just can't get that last piece of data: email. I validate the App and the login request. I get back the user's token (access_token, type: bearer), but I just can't seem to get the email address.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong token in the detail request. My solution is frankencode, but it works. Sorry to waste valuable bytes. Thanks BlueWater86.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Anything that you can get through the [API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?classic=0) will be available to you now.